# jQuery .ajax() returning 401 when authentication is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing an API request with Upcloud's API server. I sent a request with postman, and it worked just fine, but when I use .ajax(), it returns a 401. I know that the problem isn't the user and pass.

```
function listIPS(){
var url = 'https://api.upcloud.com/1.2/servers';
function make_basic_auth(name) {
    if(name === 'josh'){
        var user = 'user';
        var pass = 'pass';
    }
    if(name === 'malcolm'){
        var user = 'user';
        var pass = 'pass';
    }
    var tok = user + ':' + pass;
    var hash = window.btoa(tok);
    console.log("Basic " + hash);
    return "Basic " + hash;

}
var auth = make_basic_auth('josh');


$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "https://api.upcloud.com/1.2/account",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth)
    }, 
    success: function(data){ 
       // console.log(data);
    }
 })
}
```

This is the error I am recieving:

OPTIONS https://api.upcloud.com/1.2/account 401 (Authorization Required)

Comment: I am sure you won't be sending your auth with "GET" try "POST"

Comment: If it works in postman, this sounds like a potential CORS issue

Comment: @Mehrad, I am retrieving account info.